# Create recursive variables in tidy

Tags: r, recursion, tidyverse, dplyr, tidy

I'm trying to make a tidy solution to create an duration variable based on whether some event has happened or not. This is very simple to do in a for loop as

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df <- tibble(event = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1))
    df$dur <- NA
    df$dur[1]<-0 
    for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df$event[i]==0){
    df$dur[i] <- df$dur[i-1]+1
    }else{
    df$dur[i] <- 0
    }
    }
    print(df)
```

However, I cannot seem to find a tidy solution to this. I have tried using the purrr accumulate function but this gives me the wrong output

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(event = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1))
df <- df %>% mutate(dur = case_when(event==1 ~ 0,
                        T~purrr::accumulate(event,~.x+1,.init=-1)[-1]))
print(df)
```

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output?

Comment: If I run your `for loop` I get a new column with a sequence from 0 to 11...

Comment: How do I get the code to run to produce the output? @Sotos, there was a typo in the code and it is fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it capturing your groups via `cumsum` when `event == 1`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(event == 1)) %>% 
 mutate(dur = seq(n()) - 1)

which gives,
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 3
> # Groups:   grp [5]
>    event   grp   dur
>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
>  1     0     0     0
>  2     0     0     1
>  3     0     0     2
>  4     0     0     3
>  5     1     1     0
>  6     0     1     1
>  7     0     1     2
>  8     1     2     0
>  9     1     3     0
> 10     0     3     1
> 11     0     3     2
> 12     1     4     0
> ```

**NOTE:** You can `ungroup` and remove the column `grp` at the end If you 'd like

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution!